# Does zero sample correlation between regressor and residual mean Correlation between regressor and outcome = 0?

Tags: regression, correlation, residuals

In my econometrics professors' slides he states that:

> ”We said that $\sum_{i=1}^nX_i\hat{u}_i=0$ (where $\hat{u}$ are the residuals) **implies zero sample correlation between X and Y**“.

My problem is in understanding WHY this is (the statement in bold), or if he made a mistake and actually meant that each regressor always has zero correlation with residuals estimator, due to first order conditions used to grant OLS (even in a multivariate regression, not necessarily single variable regression).

---

*IMPORTANT EDIT: X is the regressor in a single variable linear regression and Y is the outcome of such regression*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That is clearly wrong as stated. As you say, orthogonality between regressors and residuals is true for *any* regression estimated by OLS. At the same time, the OLS estimator in a bivariate regression is known to be
$$
\hat\beta_1=\frac{\widehat{cov}(x,y)}{\widehat{var}(x)}
$$
Hence, if the statement were true, we would have a proof that, always, $\hat\beta_1=0$...

So I suppose that is a typo indeed.

Comment: Thank you very much!